# How to hide mobile keyboard using jQuery

Tags: jquery, mobile

I have a function that is prepending an html value that is input. The problem is that I want to hide the mobile keyboard once that value has been prepended. Currently I am using blur() to do this but it hides everything before someone can input a value so I can prepend it.

The function is using a class that was dynamically added when you hit the button the first time hence why the .on click is onto the body.

Any recommendations?

```
function addClassForReply() {
    $(".reply-btn").click(function(e) {
        $(".reply-btn").addClass('send-message');
    });
  }
addClassForReply();

function replyMessage() {
    $("body").on('click', '.send-message', function(e){
        var replyMessage = $(".message-reply textarea").val();
        $(".message-reply").prepend(replyMessage);
        $(".message-reply textarea").fadeOut().blur();
    });
  }
replyMessage();
```

HTML

```
<div class="message-reply">
  <textarea placeholder="Reply to Linnie"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="message-mobile-footer">
  <div class="nm-body">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- THIS IS WHERE THE CLASS GETS ADDED -->
      <a class="btn default reply-btn">Reply</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For dynamic elements I normally use `$(document).on` Not sure if that would make a difference from using `body`

Comment: I actually tried document, but it wouldn't work for some reason.

Comment: So your `.send-message` event is firing when you click `message-reply` so you cannot type text?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you need something to collapse the mobile keyboard instead of .blur() on the element, well, you can use

```
$("document").focus();
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/woozpe0u/)